# How to modify a string if the first two letters match a pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strings like this:

```
$5.00 off blah blah
5% off blah blah
This off should not match
```

I'd like to match strings that start like `^([$]?[\d.]+[%]?) off .*`

And converts them to this:

```
<strong>$5.00 off</strong> blah blah
<strong>5% off</strong> blah blah
This off should not match
```

Here is what I have right now and stuck (new to Ruby):

```
def highlight_name(name)
  words = name.dup.split

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string.gsub(/^([$]?[\d.]+[%]?) off .*/, "<strong> \\0 </strong>" )
```

`\\O` refers to the matched string.

Comment: That puts the whole string in <strong> tags. Is there a way to make only "$5 off" in strong as in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I followed this way to arrive at `.gsub(/^([$]?[\d.]+[%]? off)( .*)/, "<strong> \\1 </strong>" + '\\2' )`

Comment: that's weird: `"$ Nice weekend!".gsub(/^\$ /, "bold " + "\\0" + "bold " ) => "bold $ bold Nice weekend!"`

Comment: ahh, you're right. It was the `.*` in the answer. Removing that works with `\\0` now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on apneadiving's answer, modified to do what you want:

```
string.gsub(/^([$]?[\d.]+[%]? off)( .*)$/, '<strong>\1</strong>\2' )
```